# Two seemingly different functions with same name exist in the C program (using DWARF info), why?

Tags: c, dwarf, gnu-coreutils

I have been going through the assembly code of the `sort` program in the `GNU Coreutils` and found something I can't figure out and explain in a technological sense of why this is happening.

It all started with first disassembling the `sort` program by the command:

`~/coreutils/new_build/src (master*) » objdump --dwarf=info ./sort &> sort.objdwarf`

Which provides me with useful DWARF information that can be used to learn about the program. However, looking through it, I found out that there are two `numcompare` functions that are very different (which I will show later). For instance:

```
 <1><5978>: Abbrev Number: 55 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <5979>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x718): numcompare
...
    <5986>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x6fb0
    <598e>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x703a
    <5996>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x1464 (location list)
    <599a>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
    <599b>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x59bc>
 <2><599f>: Abbrev Number: 56 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <59a0>   DW_AT_name        : a
...
 <2><59ad>: Abbrev Number: 56 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <59ae>   DW_AT_name        : b
...
 <2><59bb>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

and second one is:

```
<1><f882>: Abbrev Number: 10 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <f883>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x718): numcompare
...
    <f88f>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x19118
    <f897>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x1957e
    <f89f>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x5d34 (location list)
    <f8a3>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
    <f8a4>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xf92e>
 <2><f8a8>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f8a9>   DW_AT_name        : a
...
 <2><f8b5>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f8b6>   DW_AT_name        : b
...
 <2><f8c2>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f8c3>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x20af): decimal_point
 ...
 <2><f8d2>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f8d3>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xa1e): thousands_sep
...
```

After `grep`ing the source code, I was able to verify that there is only one `numcompare` function:

```
~/coreutils/src (master*) » grep -Hnriw numcompare                                 
sort.c:1998:numcompare (char const *a, char const *b)
sort.c:2694:            diff = numcompare (ta, tb);
```

Upon further investigation looking through the source code, I happened to find something interesting in terms of how it is defined:

```
/* Compare strings A and B as numbers without explicitly converting them to
   machine numbers.  Comparatively slow for short strings, but asymptotically
   hideously fast. */

ATTRIBUTE_PURE
static int
numcompare (char const *a, char const *b)
{
  while (blanks[to_uchar (*a)])
    a++;
  while (blanks[to_uchar (*b)])
    b++;

  return strnumcmp (a, b, decimal_point, thousands_sep);
}
```

From this, I realized that the second DWARF information shown regarding `numcompare` is actually the information of the `strnumcmp`! As shown here:

```
<1><f810>: Abbrev Number: 5 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <f811>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <f812>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x56b8): strnumcmp
...
    <f81e>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x1957e
    <f826>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x195ac
    <f82e>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 0x5cd4 (location list)
    <f832>   DW_AT_GNU_all_tail_call_sites: 1
    <f833>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xf870>
 <2><f837>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f838>   DW_AT_name        : a
...
 <2><f844>: Abbrev Number: 6 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f845>   DW_AT_name        : b
...
 <2><f851>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f852>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x20af): decimal_point
...
 <2><f860>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <f861>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xa1e): thousands_sep
...
```

And I did a further investigation of this `strnumcmp`, and it is an outside library function used by `GNU Coreutils` that is defined as:

```
int
strnumcmp (char const *a, char const *b,
           int decimal_point, int thousands_sep)
{
  return numcompare (a, b, decimal_point, thousands_sep);
}
```

So now I'm very confused about what is going on here. The fact `ATTRIBUTE_PURE` flag is used with `static` seems to mean:

```
"ATTRIBUTE_PURE" is a function attribute in C programming language that can be used to indicate that a function has no side effects and only depends on its arguments, and "static" is a storage class specifier that indicates that the function or variable is only visible within the file it is declared in.
```

This doesn't quite help me explain what is going on here.
The main questions I wanted to ask are **why and how** are there two separate DWARF information of a function `numcompare`? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why and how are there two separate DWARF information of a function numcompare?

The functions are `static` - they have internal linkage. Every object file can have a different `static` function with the same name. For every of them, `DWARF` can be added.

One `numcompare` is here https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sort.c#L1998 and the other is here https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/gl/lib/strnumcmp-in.h#L114 . One is compiled in `sort.o` the other in `strnumcmp.o`, and object files are then linked together.

Comment: Thank you for your response, `Every object file can have a different static function with the same name.` I did not know such a thing was possible, and I think now I have a clear understanding of it.